# Web8 | Translation Manager | Translating Job timeout

Tags: translation-manager

Is there any configuration setting we can use set the max time for waiting for a job to be returned / marked as ready for returning from a Translation Provider.

Some jobs may be complex and take more time than is available before a go-live for example.

Are there any configuration/settings where we can set the time-out?

Comment: Please add details to your question on where you see the timeout (sending jobs, checking status, retrieving items, ...), and which translation management system you use.

Comment: @Lars, I've spoken with Manish and clarified his question above - I think I've answered it too but am happy to be corrected and learn more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean for the CMS to essentially *cancel* a Translation Job that has already been sent to the Translation Provider but isn't apparently flagged as ready for retrieval...

To the best of my knowledge - and what I can see from the documentation (and the config files) this is not configurable out of the box.

**Updated on correction from Lars** - *not able to cancel the Translation Job in the Tridion GUI*

You **are not** able to manually *cancel* a job in the CMS GUI but you can *cancel* a job in the World Server workflow *(other Translation Services do exist)* and there's no specific setting shown in the configs I see for

- SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 or
- Web8 *(8.1.1.)*

I'm not sure what effect the **PURGE** may have on a job that has exceeded the time but I'd be surprised if this interfered with a job that wasn't marked as Cancelled or Complete, perhaps you can update your PURGE frequency to a day and let us know (assuming you are able to agree with the Translation provider to not translate your content in the interim).

Although I'll note a **possible approach below**, you should **be cautious of** the business / business process implications of semi-automating this activity without involving a discussion with the translation provider and/or business.

- what if the large / complex (assuming Manual) translation is complete with the exception of a relatively short update that was planned imminently...

  - someone is going to be unhappy (not least the business when the provider charges them for the translation all the same *possibly*)
- if you request to cancel the translation (and hte request is made automatically) - who are the stakeholders that need to be informed (other than just the person going into World Server to hit cancel)

  - and how (this could change depending on the specific site or type of content that's being translated/cancelled

**Possible Contender**

**Updated on correction from Lars** - *not able to cancel the Translation Job in the Tridion GUI or via the Tridion API*

- Have a simple polling server
- this can check iterate through the jobs in the queue
- it can retrieve the state of the job and if it's been *sent for translation*
- the date it was sent can be interrogated
- compared to today
- compared to an agreed timespan

  - perhaps metadata on the bundle - *in Web8 this can be **sent with** the Translation content so could be used in the World Server workflow to trigger escalations*
- removed if required (i.e. send an email to whoever manages the workflow/translation jobs in the World Server GUI)

  - as hinted above - it may be more appropriate to simply escalate the fact the translation is not happening in the time expected

Comment: There is no way to cancel from the Tridion side, so the solution you suggest would have to be done on the TMS/WS side. Out of the box Tridion can communicate a due date to TMS/WS so it might be useful. I do not think setting metadata on a bundle helps, it is unlikely to make it to translation.